# Select a key value of all objects inside a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I have this code:

```
<script>
  fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout', {
    content_ids: {{orderFormProducts}},
    content_type: 'product'
  });
</script>
```

That gives me the entire array:

```
content_ids: [
               {
                 "id":"1",
                 "name": "product name",
                 "sku": "10",
                 "skuName": "sku name"
               },
               {
                 "id": "2",
                 "name": "product name",
                 "sku":"20",
                 "skuName": "sku name"
               }
             ]
```

And what I need is to get only the `sku` value of all objects inside that array, like so:

```
content_ids: ["10", "20"]
```

If I use `{{orderFromProducts}}[0].sku` I can get the `sku` value from the 0 indexed object, but I need from all objects inside the array like mentioned before, and `{{orderFromProducts}}.sku` doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: iterate the array... and get the sku from each object

Answer (score 0):

```
content_ids.map(el=>el.sku);
```

Please http://google.it before you ask, you could have found
 https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map.

Comment: Be warned the .map() function is not available in older browsers.(specifically IE 8 or earlier)

Comment: @chambo even my grandpa isnt using IE8 anymore...

Comment: @chambo in this case just switch to a loop with `for` :)

Comment: @Jonasw - your grandpa is hip to the game! Despite your hip grandpa, there are still sites that have to maintain compatibility with IE 8 and even older.  Figured I'd mention it.  Better safe than sorry. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Use [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example).

```
orderFromProducts.map(function(product) {
  return product.sku;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.map()` to create a new array populated with `sku` values.

```js
let content_ids = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "product name",
    "sku": "10",
    "skuName": "sku name"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "product name",
    "sku": "20",
    "skuName": "sku name"
  }
];

let skus = content_ids.map(x=>x.sku);

console.log(skus);
```

For old school browsers like IE 7, use a `for` instead.

```js
var content_ids = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "product name",
    "sku": "10",
    "skuName": "sku name"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "product name",
    "sku": "20",
    "skuName": "sku name"
  }
];

var skus = [];
for (var i = 0, len = content_ids.length; i < len; i++) {
  skus.push(content_ids[i].sku);
}


console.log(skus);
```